# Drupal 7 content copying

Tags: import, drupal-7, copy

I wants to copy all nodes of a specific content type from one Drupal site to another drupal site (Both totally different sites | different DBs | different filesystem)...Please suggest best approach.

Answer (score 0):

best way I found was with [node_export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) and [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)

hope it helps

PR